# How to deduct or Add new quantity in products

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2010

I have created 3 tables, 1.Product, 2.POrders, 3.POrderDetails, my question is when i add more than 3 line items in POrderDetails where do I save the product Quantity and how to deduct or add new quantity in product quantity with VBA Code or any mean?

Regards
Jazzi

Answer (score 0):

Here's a logic. If you want to add, you have to create a form where it accepts addition for quantity. You can use a textbox and button where you can insert the qty. Next, you have to code the button, store the qty inputted to a variable, next fetch the product quantity from the db and store it too to a variable. finally, get their total and store it to the qty field in your db.

for deducting, it is better to code it in your btnOrder or whatever you call it. fetch again the qty from the db, store it to a variable. but first in your order process you need to have quantity for the product that is ordered, store it again to a variable.  dbquantity - orderquantity. then save it to the db.